# Cleanest way of decreasing space between content in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

I use Bootstrap v3 and AdminLTE. Here I want to decrease the space between each content. 
[image]

When I just set margin-left and margin-right, the right-margin of rightmost content and the left margin of far left content are affected which I dont want to. How is the cleanest way to achieve that?

Comment: I think  it doesn't need my code since my question is general enough @SmokeyDawson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the **[`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** and **[`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)** pseudo-classes to apply rules to any element *other* than the first match.

In your case, you'll want to apply `margin-right` to `:not(:first-of-type)`
(or `margin-left` to `:not(:last-of-type)`).

This can be seen in the following, simplified example:

```css
.item {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item:not(:first-of-type) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">One</div>
<div class="item">Two</div>
<div class="item">Three</div>
<div class="item">Four</div>
```

Comment: Not really sure why this was downvoted. Can the downvoter please explain so I can improve the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :nth-child selector, or what I prefer is using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).  Specifically, if you set the container to `justify-content: space-between`, it will create even spacing between each element but also leave the first and last element at the ends.

I'd also recommend upgrading to Bootstrap v4.. it is so much better, and includes their own shorthand flexbox.